# DrRacket 6.1 error says lexer is undefined

Tags: racket

I'm trying to make a lexer of characters and numbers only, but I'm getting an error saying **lexer** is undefined. I'll use it for files in the future, but for now I'm testing with keyboard input. This is my code:

```
    (require parser-tools/lex-sre)
    (define simpleCharNumLexer
      (lexer
       [(:+ (:or (char-range #\a #\z) (char-range #\A #\Z)))
        ; =>
        (cons `(ID ,(string->symbol lexeme))
              (analyze input-port))]
       [(:: (:? #\-) (:+ (char-range #\0 #\9)))
        ; =>
        (cons `(INT ,(string->number lexeme))
              (analyze input-port))]))
```

And this is the error:
**lexer: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier**

I'm using DrRacket 6.1 and Pretty Big as language environment. I think lexer is a module, but how do I find it or define it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add (require parser-tools/lex)

The lex-sre just provides an alternative notation for regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you, now the error of lexer undefined is solved. I'll mark it as answer, although now I'm getting an undefined operator error in my regular expressions from that same code. As you said I need an another notation now. Anyway, the question was about the lexer error, not about regex so this is solved. Thanks again, very much.

Comment: The operator exported from lex-sre is named +, if you import it with an : as prefix it works: `(require parser-tools/lex 
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre))`